# jboss url form servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, jboss6.x

Im trying to create a simple servlet in a war file and deploy it to a jboss 6 in all configuration. My problem is that i get a test jsp file to work with url "localhost:8080/workbox/" but i cant call the servlet in "localhost:8080/workbox/TestServlet/". The servlet returns a "404 Not available". Any help would be appreciated:

Servlet source code:

```
package se.marthin.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

       @Override
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                            HttpServletResponse resp)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
          resp.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
          writer.println("<h1> asdasdadsadsasddas" +
                         "</h1>");
          writer.close();
       }
}
```

Package structure in compiled .war file:

```
META-INF/
    MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
    web.xml
    classes/
        se/marthin/web/TestServlet.class
    lib/
index.jsp
```

Source code for web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What do you have in the web.xml?

Comment: Can you try declaring the servlet in your web.xml? May the annotations are ignored by the container.

Comment: I works with xml declaration, not sure why its not picking up my annotation though.

Comment: Can you try specifying servlet api version 3 in your web.xml?

Comment: <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">

Comment: Can you try that in your web.xml?

Comment: Ahh you right ofcourse! How could i miss that! =)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the configuration of the servlet to the web.xml.

Like:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>se.marthin.web.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: you do not need to use any xml when using annotations in this case.